# Definition of ring of regular functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshornes "Algebraic Geometry" the ring of regular functions is defined over affine and quasi-affine varieties. In the case of an affine variety I don´t understand how this ring looks like. Because a regular function is only defined on open sets, we have to add and multiply regular functions which are defined on different subsets of the affine variety. How does that work?

Comment: The ring of regular functions is the ring of functions regular on the entire variety.

Comment: Oh yeah now I understand. My misunderstanding came from  forgetting that we look at the subspace topology on the Variety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hartshorne defines the "ring of regular functions" as follows (Chapter I.3).
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $I\subseteq A:=k[x_1,..,x_n]$ be a prime ideal. Let $Z:=Z(I)$ be the zero set of $I$. Let $U\subseteq Z$ be a zariski open set and let $f:U\rightarrow k$ be a function.

Definition (D1). We say $f$ is regular at $p\in U$ iff there is an open set $p\in U(p) \subseteq U$ and functions $u,v\in A$ with $v\neq 0$ on $U(p)$, such that $f(x)=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$ on $U(p)$. we say $f$ is regular at $U$ iff f is regular at all points in $U$

Let $\mathcal{O}(U)$ be the set of functions that are regular at $U$.

Lemma. $\mathcal{O}(U)$ is a $k$-algebra.

Proof. Let $f,g$ be regular at $p\in U$. There are open sets $U(p), V(p)$ containing $p$ with $f=\frac{u}{v}$ on $U(p)$ and $g=\frac{w}{z}$ on $V(p)$, with $v,z\neq 0$. it follows $f+g=\frac{uz+wv}{vz}$ on $W(p):=U(p)\cap V(p)$, and $vz\neq 0$ on $W(p)$,
hence if $f,g\in \mathcal{O}(U)$ it follows $f+g\in \mathcal{O}(U)$. Similarly $fg\in \mathcal{O}(U)$ and if $a\in k$ it follows $af\in \mathcal{O}(U)$. The Lemma follows.

For any open sets $V\subseteq U$ there are canonical restriction maps (restriction of functions)

$$\rho_{UV}: \mathcal{O}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(V)$$

and you get (...) a sheaf of $k$-algebras $\mathcal{O}_Z$ on $Z$, with the property that
$(Z, \mathcal{O}_Z)$ is a (locally) ringed space.  It is a good exercise to verify the sheaf axioms from Hartshorne, Chapter II. The definition D1 is local and you may define this for any quasi projective variety as defined in HH Chapter I.
Hence it makes sense to speak about sheaves of functions for the varieties introduced in Chapter I in Hartshornes book.

Note: Using D1 it follows the ring $\mathcal{O}_Z(U)$ is a "ring of functions" on the open set $U$, and this is a bit "more intuitive" than the construction of the structure sheaf in Chapter II in the same book. In Chapter II in the same book the sheaf of sections $\mathcal{O}_X$ of a scheme $X$ is introduced, and you should think about sections $s\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ as "functions" taking values in the residue field $\kappa(x)$. Given a section $s$ you get canonically an element in the local ring at $x$, $s_x\in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and you may define the "value" $s(x)\in \kappa(x)$ because of the canonical map

$$ ev_x: \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \rightarrow \kappa(x)$$

and by definition $s(x):=ev_x(s_x)\in \kappa(x)$. The element $s(x)$ is the "value" of the section $s$ at the point $x$. What is "unintuitive" here is that the residue field $\kappa(x)$ may change with the point $x$.

Here you will find a discussion of the "value" of a section $s$.

[About the reducedness in algebraic geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928532/about-the-reducedness-in-algebraic-geometry/3942701#3942701)

Example. If $X:=Spec(\mathbb{R}[x])$ and $\mathfrak{m}:=(p_z(x))$ the maximal ideal generated by a polynomial of degree two with non-real roots, it follows the residue field is the field of complex numbers. If we want to "calculate" the value of a section $s$ at the point $x$ corresponding to $\mathfrak{m}$, we have to choose an explicit isomorphism

$$\kappa(x) \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(p_z(x)) \cong \mathbb{C}.$$

We have two choices: A complex zero $z$ of the polynomial $p_z(x)$ or the conjugate $\overline{z}$. Hence the value of $s$ at $x$ depends on this choice. What does not depend on this choice is if the section $s$ is zero or not, and this is what we are interested in when we are doing algebraic geometry: We want to study the locus of points where the section $s$ is zero.

Example. If $X:=Spec(A)$ and $s\in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)\cong A$ is a global section, it follows the "locus of points" $Z_s$ where the global section $s$ is zero has a natural scheme structure: It is the subscheme $V((s))\subseteq X$, where $(s)\subseteq A$ is the ideal defined by the element $s$. When studying sections of sheaves in algebraic geometry, you are mostly interested in the locus where the section is zero or where it is non-zero $D(s)\cong Spec(A_s)$. At the level of topological spaces you may write $X$ as a disjoint union

$$X=D(s) \cup V(s).$$